# Scaling in clustering with k-means

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have a set of data on revenue and cost in 2 different currencies A and B. So I am just curious if k-means result changes if I make the following modification

a) If I run k-means once with currency A and once with currency B, would the clustering change? My hypothesis is that it does because of scaling.

b) If I run k-means once with revenue in currency A and cost in currency B and the once with revenue in currency B and cost in currency A? My intuition says it also changes but can't explain it properly.

c) So if I standardize both cost and revenue so they dont depend on currency any more. Would the k means result remain the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

K-means is *very* sensitive to scale.

But it only matters how the attributes are scaled relative to each other. It's easy to see that scaling the entire data set with some a>0 does not matter.

If *all* attributes are in currency A and transformed to currency B, the result must not change. But it will change (and often substantially so) if only some attributes are changed.

Standardization is a hot-fix for this, but it's not more than a heuristic. It gives all attributes the same influence on a very high level, but that may even be undesirable. In particular if the data distribution is skewed (and monetary values often are) and 0 has a well-defined meaning (it has here) then standardization often is the wrong approach.

If this question arises, this usually indicates that k-means is the wrong tool. You have attributes of different meaning, and shouldn't be treating them the same. You will probably get some result, but you will not be able to prove anything anymore. You'll not *know* if this is good, or "correct".

Answer (score 0):

A) No they won't.

B) Yes they will.

C) Yes they will.

Option B makes no sense to me. You are then comparing (say) dollars to yen. Since a yen is worth about a penny, any variable measured in yen will be 100 times more important than if measured in dollars, purely as a statistical artifact.

Option C changes the measure of distance (which is crucial in cluster analysis) from the unit (dollars or yen or whatever) to standard deviations of that unit. Once the variables are all on the same scale, some will have much greater range than the others. If your only variables are revenue and cost, perhaps they are on roughly the same scale (hopefully with revenue a bit higher!). But, in general, this isn't necessarily so.

Since the units (dollars or yen or whatever) have a lot of meaning, my intuition is to not standardize.  We know what a dollar is. We don't know what a standard deviation of a dollar is.

But I'm also not sure if you should use currency untransformed. Particularly if your data varies over a range of companies (or whatever the subjects are) then you might consider taking logs. But it depends on your purpose.